# AngularJS cannot find module with latest RequireJS

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, angularjs, requirejs

I just upgraded to RequireJS 2.1.1 - I have an AngularJS app I'm loading with it. I get "No module: app" from angular before the main define runs.

It works fine on RequireJS 2.0.1. Any idea what might have changed?

Here's is public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  <script data-main="main" src="requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is public/main.coffee

```
require.config

  shim:
    underscore: exports: '_'
    ngResource:
      exports: 'angular'
      deps: ['angular']
    angular:
      exports: 'angular'
      deps: ['jquery']
    jquery: exports: 'jQuery'

  paths:
    underscore: 'underscore/index'
    angular: 'AngularJS/angular'
    ngResource: 'angular-modules/resource'
    jquery: 'jquery/jquery'

# Bootstrap angularjs using requirejs. 
define [], (require) ->
  angular = require 'angular'
  ngResource = require 'ngResource'

  TestCtrl = require 'controllers/TestCtrl'

  ## ROUTER ###########
  app = angular.module 'app', ['ngResource'], ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider.when '/test', {templateUrl: 'partials/test.html', controller: TestCtrl}
    $routeProvider.otherwise {redirectTo: '/test'}

  return app
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should manually bootstrap angular and remove the ng-app attribute in that case since the module is not available on dom ready:

```
angular.bootstrap document, ['app']
```

at the end of your define function

Comment: Interesting. It still throws the no module error, but then the app loads afterwards. Still seems weird. Do you know what changed between 2.0 and 2.1?

Comment: If I also remove the ng-app declaration on the html tag it works with no error

Comment: I still don't understand *why* I need to do that though. Shouldn't I be able to get it working without calling bootstrap?

Comment: Because the auto bootstrap requires your angular modules to be ready on DOM ready, and RequireJS can't guarantee that

Comment: thx! just lost half a day to understand why i had those error messages because i had ng-app in my DOM!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this js file: angular-resource.js